# VBA - day and month values flip when I get my macro save the csv file

Tags: vba, csv, date

I am having trouble pasting dates to a csv file, as once the file is saved and reopened the day and month digits flip.

The date is copied from one of my excel cells ("09/07/2021", and its "dd/mm/yyyy" format)
I open an existing csv file, insert this date in one of the columns and in the next column add 10 to that date. I run a loop to repeat this for 9 rows.

before saving this is how it looks
[image]

Once I get my code to save the csv file and I re-open, this is what I see

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? my codes are below.

```
Sub date_issue_csv3()

'take the date from another workbook
dateV = Worksheets("main").Range("c2").Value

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Workbooks.Open (Range("c11").Value)
rowsC = 9

For i = 1 To rowsC
Range("g1").Offset(i, 0).Value = dateV
Range("g1").Offset(i, 1).Value = DateAdd("d", 10, dateV)
Next i


Workbooks(wb2).Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Use ISO date notation: `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Comment: ok, how and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fallen foul of this one myself enough times. `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` date formats are easily misinterpreted for anything up to the 12th of any month.
As per @Maciej_Los's suggestion, ISO date format `yyyy/mm/dd` is universally recognised and never gets misinterpreted by Excel or other programs (because honestly what psychopath would try `yyyy/dd/mm`).

Change your loop as follows:

```
For i = 1 To rowsC
Range("g1").Offset(i, 0).Value = dateV
Range("g1").Offset(i, 1).Value = Format(DateAdd("d", 10, dateV), "yyyy/mm/dd")
Next i
```

Comment: thanks @Spencer Barnes, still the same issue. although what I also saw is if I manually save the csv i get the correct format. but if I get my code to save the csv the problem persists ..any ideas?

Comment: thanks - finally worked had to slightly change the code  - Range("g1").Offset(i, 1).Value = Format(DateAdd("d", 10, dateV), "dd/mm/yyyy")